# Calling values from my sql database isn't working properly

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

This is my code:

```
<?php
include("inc/incfiles/header.inc.php");
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
if (!isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
    header("location: index.php");
}
else {
    echo "Welcome, user number " . $user_id . ". This is you're newsfeed!";
    echo "<br><a href=\"logout.php\">Log Off?</a>";
}

echo "<br><br>";

$userFname = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$userLname = mysql_query("SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");

echo "First Name: " . $userFname . "<br>";
echo "Last Name: " . $userLname . "<br>"; ?>
```

The header.inc.php file is just for the sql connect and the html header.

My problem right now is that when I call the first name and last name, it just gives outputs 'Resource id #6' and 'Resource id #7'. I don't understand why it's not displaying the actual first and last names??

Comment: You are not accessing the results `mysql_fetch_assoc` (or some of the other similar functions) on the result set. You also only need one query to access two pieces of data in the same table.

Comment: if its answered then accept an answer by placing a checkmark.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer as _accepted_.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `mysql_query()` function does not return the "stuff" in your `SELECT` clause. Rather, it returns a resource that you can use to get that "stuff".

Try this:

```
// Obtain the resource:
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");

// From that resource, get a row of data as an associative array
// The keys in that array will match the names in your SELECT clause
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);

echo "First Name: " . $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns a result set that you still need to parse. Add this step:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$userFname = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo $userFname->first_name; //will print the user's first name
```

[mysql_fetch_object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) will initialize an object with the table's columns as attributes.

Given your case, I would probably just fetch one user record and use both name attributes from within the same object:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$user = mysql_fetch_object($result);
echo $user->first_name;
echo $user->last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

the function "mysql_query" doesn't actually return a result value, you'll next need to call something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$userFname = $row["first_name"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$userLname = $row["last_name"];
```

Or even better:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($result) {
    $userFname = $row["first_name"];
    $userLname = $row["last_name"];
}
```

Comment: No need to do two queries - just `select first_name, last_name...`

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() returns a `result` resource, not the actua data.

You need to extract the data with one of the `fetch` functions. Your code should look something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE id=$user_id");
if ($result === false) {
     echo mysql_error;

} else {
 list ($userFname, $userLname) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
}
```