# Getting Resource id #3 Error in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, echo

I ran this code and I got a Resource id #3 error where it should have showed the full movies table.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("treehouse_movie_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies") 
or die(mysql_error()); 
echo $data;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385404

Answer (score 9):

This is not an `error` Your query is getting executed and you are getting appropriate resource from [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as it should be returned.

To get the response you have to use [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("treehouse_movie_db") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

**SUGGESTION:** mysql_* are no longer maintained .Try switching to [mysqli_*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php%E2%80%8E) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting an error, the MySQL API is just doing what you're asking it to: echoing the contents of `$data`, which is a MySQL query resource at this point. Extend the code to actually retrieve the results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($data))
    var_dump($row);
```

And you'll see the output.

Note that the [mysql_* API is deprecated since PHP 5.5 by the way](https://www.php.net/mysql_query).

Answer (score 0):

`Resourse id #3` means that the `$data` variable was used to open a resourse, it is not an error.
If you were to open another resourse, like a file, using:

```
$var=fopen('myfile','a+');
echo $var;
```

You would get `Resourse id $4` as a result.

So to get the output you desire, you need to use a loop.
It is described in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php).