# PHP Array not being delivered

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in a database column called "gcmregid". 
I access this data by calling:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
    $r = mysql_query("select * FROM table");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $result = array(
    'gcmregid' => $row["gcmregid"]
    );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should deliver an array, due to result = array? 
I took this logic from here: [Getting Resource id #3 Error in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417308/getting-resource-id-3-error-in-mysql)

.Then I thaught using a loop would be helpful, such as:

```
$userCount = $db->getUserCount(); // counting said table
$registation_ids = array(); // again create array
for($i=0; $i < $userCount; $i++)
{
    $gcmRegId = $db->getGCMRegID($selUsers[$i]);    
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($gcmRegId);        
    //Add RegIds retrieved from DB to $registration_ids
    array_push($registation_ids, $row['gcmregid']); // this creates an array consisting of gcmregid s ?               
}
```

It doesn't work either.
Any input would be really appreciated right now...
Thanks

Comment: You are overwriting  `$result` in every iteration of the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going wrong, but if the problem is that it's returning a single item: that's because you keep making a *new* array with every iteration, discarding the old one. If you want to collect all the rows, make a new array outside of the loop and then add the results to it:

```
public function getAllUsers() {
    $r = mysql_query("select * FROM table");
    $result = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $result[] = array (
    'gcmregid' => $row["gcmregid"]
    );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thanks Erik for pointing this out. So I just tried using your function- result is here an array with **all gcmregid 's** right? I just used it like this: $users = $db->getAllUsers();  //getting array of gcmregids?      This runs exactly for all entries , but claims the entries are wrong.. (which they definitively aren't).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider working more on how you name your functions. If you are trying to get `gcmregid`, the method should not say `getAllUsers`. Anyway, did you try the following:

```
public function get_gcmregid() {
    $query_result = mysql_query("select * FROM table");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
    return $result[0]['gcmregid'];
}
```

OR if you are trying to get all `gcmregid` in one shot:

```
public function get_gcmregid() {
    $query_result = mysql_query("select * FROM table");
    $i=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
         $result[$i++] = $row['gcmregid'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thanks, yeah the names are suboptimal- will look into those, but first I need it running. Either way, I want the function to return all gcmregid in one shot, you're right. Could I also write:   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
         $result[] = $row['gcmregid'];
    }
    return $result;                ?